# create extended 'copy' of existing c# class

Tags: c#, function, class, sqlconnection

**There are** many classes around like:

```
var db = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
```

you **can use** ist like:

```
db.Open();
db.Close();
//...
```

so **what I'm searching for** is a kind of perfect copy of the class:

```
public class SqlConnection{
    private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection db;

    public SqlConnection() {
        //create SqlConnection
        db = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    }
    public void Open() {
        db.Open();
    }
    //...
}
```

so that I can use it like a normal class, but with my own **little customisations**:

```
db.Open();
db.Close();
//...
db.MyOwnFunktion();
```

Is there a quick solution like a visual-studio-build-in function to do so?

Comment: Probably you mean inheritance from SqlConnection and extend it with your own function ?

Comment: `SqlConnection` is sealed and cannot be inherited. You need to create a wrapper. What's wrong with the code you posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can do several things:

1. [Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) - create your own class that will inherit from a different one and will add more functionality
2. Write extension methods - For your case of `SqlConnection` due to it being a [`sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) class that is what you should do (over option1)

---

Short example of extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this SqlConnection connection, int input)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

//And then when you want to use it:
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
connection.DoSomething(3);
```

Comment: so that what I'm looking for. Could you add a line o code so that I know how to do?

Comment: @Gilad_Green I wanted to do so earlier, but I coudn't ;) now i can